# How to Set correct HTTP Header and Body

Tags: iphone, html, http, post, nsurlrequest

I want to upload image data object to server(.html) with file name (123456700.png).

This code has no error, but uploading is not worked.

Set Header

```
// Initial Setting
NSString *urlString = @"http://121.78.147.19/uploadfile.html";
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];  

// Set Heeader
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// type: text/html;charset=UTF-8;
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/html;charset=UTF-8; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
```

Set Body (imgData has no problem, I checked imgData.length)

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Disposition: form-data, name="image" filename="123456700.png" ???
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"123456700.png\"\r\n"] 
                  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// Type: application/octet-stream ??? 
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imgData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Run (No Error, resData is html text data.

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *resData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

==============================================================================

/uploadfile.html screen capture (Chrome / Below Info and text is html source code.)

Page has no problem. Uploading works fine via web-page.

A button with text "파일 선택" is "Select File" button.

-------------------------------Web Page Screen Capture----------------------------------------i

[image: /uploadfile.html]

Comment: Did your server receive any data? And how do you get the imgData

Comment: I can't check server. and imgData = [NSData dataWithFile:~~]; I checked path and data length. imgData has no problem

Comment: Your html does not accept any post request data. You have to use server programming to get it.

Comment: @Hanon What 'server programming' means? Server works on chrome or ie browser. I didn't have server programming experience...

Answer (score 0):

1. the http body data is in wrong order,
2. content type is wrong

see more detail specification here: [Form-based File Upload in HTML](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt)

Comment: 2. Change @"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" ?

Comment: I do not know 1... I am poor to english. I am not English user.

Comment: Change name...is right? @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"fileData\"; filename=\"123456700.png\"\r\n"